# Can't ping linux image running on Qemu

Tags: linux, qemu, buildroot

I am very new to this
but i used build root to built kernel for arm-versatilepb then i am using qemu to run it
with the following command:
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 256 -kernel zImage -dtb versatile-pb.dtb -drive file=rootfs.ext2,if=scsi,format=raw -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyAMA0,115200" -serial stdio -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user

when i run the image from qemu and do the ifconfig :#ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56
inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

so the problem is i can ping any site i try from my qemu machine
but when i try to ping the qemu machine(with ip :10.0.2.15) from my host machine it is not responding
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect KVM guest vm from mac hosts by ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135075/how-to-connect-kvm-guest-vm-from-mac-hosts-by-ssh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is the same as the answer to this one:
[How to connect KVM guest vm from mac hosts by ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135075/how-to-connect-kvm-guest-vm-from-mac-hosts-by-ssh)

You're using user-mode networking, which doesn't allow the outside world to connect in to the guest, except if you set up specific port forwarding on your QEMU command line.

Answer (score 1):

The network configuration you are using (-net user) configures qemu to use a SLiRP network which does not support ICMP packets from the host machine into the qemu virtual NIC.

See https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Network_backend_types, where it states that "in general, ICMP traffic does not work", and "the guest is not directly accessible from the host or the external network".

Answer (score 0):

### Context

I had a similar problem setting up EVE-NG (Ubuntu 20.04 in the end) on a linux host (I use Arch btw). The thing is that EVE-NG exposes a webserver that I could not reach after setting it up in QEMU ([here's how, if you're interested](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40CyZ8wjYR8))

### Networking modes

Understanding the modes available to you is the first steps towards finding a solution. To keep it short, there are two interesting modes in here:

1. Usermode networking (a.k.a. [SLIRP](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_(SLIRP)). This is the default, hence the `10.0.2.15` ip address)

   - Host cannot access the Guest OS is any way (ping, web-server, etc...) [out of the box](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_get_SSH_access_to_a_guest).
   - Guest OS can access the host (at least ping is working)
   - Guest OS can access the internet
2. Bridged networking, usually setup via [taps](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_use_tap_with_a_wireless_adapter_on_the_host).

   - VM gets its own IP address on the same subnet as the host (can be configured).
   - VM can communicate directly with other devices on the network.
   - VM can access the internet, other devices can access it.

### Solution

Based on what was pointed out above, looks like a bridged network is the way to go in this example. (I will not delve into security implications since that's beyond this thread)

You can pretty much do everything I'm about to describe with the CLI, but I'll be using `virt-manager` here.

- Add a new virtual network. In this example, I added the 192.168.122.0/24 network (which is not in conflict with any other network I have. I also share how the `XML` config would look like). Notice how I keep DHCP enabled by default. If you want to configure your own addressed, you can disable it.

[image: Setting up a TAP]
[image: Setting up a TAP - Code]

- Update the VM NIC accordingly with the name created above (**virbr0** in this example). For which device model to use, see [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597789/virtio-vs-e1000-vs-rtl8139-whats-the-difference). virtio is a good default.

[image: Update the Virtual Machine's Network Interface Card]

Now if you shutdown the virtual machine and open it again (don't reboot, do a shutdown so "hardware" changes are picked up), you should have both internet access as well as host-to-guest and guest-to-host communication.

One the Host OS, you should also see the newly created `virbr0` and a route to that network:

```bash
$ ifconfig

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:7c:4d:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
       ...

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ...

$ route -n                                                                    

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
...
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

What I like about `virt-manager` is that you don't have to worry about deleting left-over routes and whatnot once you're done with the VMs. Simply bringing down the network TAP is enough to clean everything up. Here's an [interesting read](https://www.spad.uk/posts/really-simple-network-bridging-with-qemu/) if you want to see how the manual approach would work.